# How to stop keyboard from distorting ListView in Drawerlayout?

Tags: android, listview, android-xml, drawerlayout

Okay, so I have a friendslist feature in a drawer layout like so:

[image] [image]

As you can see, I need some way of the LinearLayout holding the edittext and button to push the listview above it upwards, instead of appearing on top of it. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: My code, as requested

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter friend name" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:text="Add" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is it possible you set the `ListViews` height to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`?

Comment: Post your layout xml code

Comment: No difference I'm afraid @XaverKapeller.

Comment: But something like this must be the problem. The `ListView` should have become scrollable when the keyboard is opened if it had `match_parent`. Most likely there is something wrong with your layout.

Comment: Try adding a bottom padding to the `ListView`. The padding should be as high as the EditText and button.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you are using a RelativeLayout as your main view group. Switch that to a LinearLayout and give the ListView a height of 0 and a weight of 1. Give the bottom layout a height of wrapcontent and no weight.

Don't forget to give the orientation to your LinearLayouts (vertical or horizontal).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply switch your activity's windowSoftInputMode flag to "adjustPan". Check the official documentation 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft
for more info.

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> 
</activity>
```